# Scroll to next <div> Using jQuery using css ::after element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to scroll on to next div I am not sure for the jQuery as I am not so expert in it so I want to scroll to next div by clicking on the down arrow. can anyone please help me?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('sub-div::after').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).closest().next('sub-div').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.sub-div{
  height:50px;
  width:100%;
  padding-bottom:12px;
}
.main-div .sub-div::after{
  content: "\f078";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  position: relative;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.main-div .sub-div:hover::after{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="main-div">
  <div class="sub-div">
    Some Content Here...
  </div>
  <div class="sub-div">
    Some Content Here...
  </div>
  <div class="sub-div">
    Some Content Here...
  </div>
  <div class="sub-div">
    Some Content Here...
  </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Use id to the div and call id using that particular icon, No need to use any other things!

Comment: As you can see I am adding Icon on all `<div>` each Icon is by **CSS**  @user7357089 how can I link each Icon to different div next to the Icon ?

Comment: you can add icons for each of the div, or do you want to achieve it by this single code?

Answer (score 0):

Try with [**`scrollTop()`**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and [**`Animate()`**](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

> 1. `sub-div` is class name so mention with `.sub-div`.
> 2. And use with `scrollTop` onclick with `sub-div` it was find next div
>      `top`.Then body scroll with that position.
> 3. And also `pseudo element` not working with this click function.so
>      try with **`children`** element for down arrow

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.sub-div p').click(function() {

   var tops = (jQuery(this).parent().next('.sub-div').position() == undefined)? 0: jQuery(this).parent().next('.sub-div').position().top;
   $('body').animate({
   scrollTop :tops
   },1000);
  });
 
});
```

```css
.sub-div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  margin:20px auto;
}
 p{
  position: relative;
top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:green;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="main-div">
  <div class="sub-div">
    1st Content Here..
    <p class="fa fa-angle-down"><p>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-div">
   2nd Content Here...
     <p class="fa fa-angle-down"><p>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-div">
    3rd Content Here...
      <p class="fa fa-angle-down"><p>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-div">
    4th Content Here...
      <p class="fa fa-angle-down"><p>
  </div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Scroll to specific div simple by HTML

```css
.main-div{
height: 10px;
}
.sub-div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
}
.main-div .sub-div::after{
  content: "\f078";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  position: relative;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.main-div .sub-div:hover::after{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="main-div" >
 
  <div class="sub-div" id="first">
  <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
  asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasd
  asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfa
  asdfasdfasdf</p>
  <a href="#sec">click here</a>
 </div>

 <div class="sub-div" id="sec">
  <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
  asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasd
  asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfa
  asdfasdfasdf</p>
  <a href="#third">click here</a>
 </div>

 <div class="sub-div" id="third">
  <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
  asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasd
  asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfa
  asdfasdfasdf</p>
  <a href="#fourth">click here</a>
 </div>

 <div class="sub-div" id="fourth">
  <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
  asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasd
  asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfa
  asdfasdfasdf</p>
  <a href="#first">click here</a>
 </div>  
   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-elements are not part of the DOM at all so you can't bind any events directly to them, you can only bind to their parent elements. It's better to append an element and bind the click event to it. Take a look at below snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".sub-div").each(function(){
    $(this).append("<span></span>").click(function(){ 
     $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop:$(this).next().offset().top}, 'slow')
    });
  })
 
});
```

```css
.sub-div{
  height:500px;
  width:100%;
  padding-bottom:12px;
}
.main-div .sub-div span::after{
  content: "\f078";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  position: relative;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.main-div .sub-div span:hover::after{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="main-div">
  <div class="sub-div">
    1. Some Content Here...
  </div>
  <div class="sub-div">
    2. Some Content Here...
  </div>
  <div class="sub-div">
    3. Some Content Here...
  </div>
  <div class="sub-div">
   4. Some Content Here...
  </div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will make it go the next div when the div is clicked.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".sub-div").each(function(){
    $(this).append("<span></span>").click(function(){ 
     if($(this).next().is(".sub-div")){
      var target = $(this).next(".sub-div");


      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
      }, 2000);
    }
    });
  })
});
```

```css
.sub-div{
  padding-bottom:12px;
}
.main-div .sub-div span::after{
  content: "\f078";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  position: relative;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.main-div .sub-div span:hover::after{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="main-div">
  <div class="sub-div">
    Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...
  </div>
  <div class="sub-div">
    Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...
  </div>
  <div class="sub-div">
    Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...
  </div>
  <div class="sub-div">
    Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...Some Content Here...
  </div>   
</div>
```